# Does REST web service has broker?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

In SOAP, I see that there is a broker for orchestrating the connections between components. I want to know that is there a similar broker in REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no broker in SOAP, as long as somebody introduces one between the components (consumer, provider). SOAP is just a protocol. It can be used without a broker/ESB, for instance with direct http connections.
The same applies for REST.